# Python3.6 - checking if file is in local folder before downloading from internet does not work properly

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.6, os.path

I have written a program to download pdf-files from arxiv.org. It will not be a download bot, but I use it at the moment to get my program to work. If I get it to work it can be a generic code. Please read the bot-warning on arxiv.org if you intend to use the code. They refer to Amazon for bulk download.

As I do not want to download the same file twice I do a check to see if it is already on the computer in the folder of the python-file. The problem is it does not work properly, because sometimes the program recognize files on the hard drive and does not download, but sometimes it downloads the files again.

It means I believe the code to do something, but it does something else.

The code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
import os.path

axx= '.pdf'

# specify the URL of the archive here
archive_url = "https://arxiv.org/list/quant-ph/new"
def get_links():

    # create response object
    r = requests.get(archive_url)

    # create beautiful-soup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib')

    # find all links on web-page
    links = soup.findAll('a', attrs = {'title' : 'Download PDF'})
    #take out the numbering of pdf-files on arxiv.
    #links = re.findall(('\d+'+'.'+'\d+'), links)
    # filter the link sending with .mp4 or other file type
    ''''
    source 1
    https://arxiv.org/list/math/new
    html =  a href="/pdf/1705.04681" title="Download PDF">pdf</a>

    source 2
    '''
    #_links = [archive_url + link['href'] for link in links if link['href'].endswith('mp4')]
    file_links = ['https://arxiv.org'+link['href'] for link in links if link['href']+axx]

    #rinse duplicates fomr list if file already is on harddrive
    file_links = list(set(file_links))


    for link in file_links:
        if os.path.isfile(os.getcwd()+'/'+link.split('/')[-1]+axx) == True:
                          file_links.remove(link)              
        else:
            return file_links

def download_series(file_links):
    for link in file_links:

        # obtain filename by splitting url and getting
        # last string
        file_name = (link.split('/')[-1]+axx)
        print("Downloading file:%s"%file_name)

        # create response object
        r = requests.get(link, stream = True)

        # download started
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 2048*2048):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)

        print("%s downloaded!\n"%file_name)
    print("All files downloaded!")
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # getting all pdf links
    file_links = get_links()
    # download all pdfs
    download_series(file_links)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop in `get_links` removes local files, else returns all `file_links` . I think `get_links` should return a list of pdfs to download instead ( if not found on disk ). Example :

```
file_links = list(set(file_links))
return [ 
    link for link in file_links 
    if not os.path.isfile(os.getcwd()+'/'+link.split('/')[-1]+axx) 
]
```